# Dynamic Data for NSCombobox

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nscombobox

How to dynamically add NSComboBox data using objective c and cocoa framework in xcode?

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSLog(@"View controller instance with view: %@", self.view);


    char* data = getData(); // I will be using data to populate records below


    // Setup combo box with data from getData() instead of dummy apple, bag, cat, dog
    self.myRecords = @[@“apple”, @“bag”, @“cat”, @“dog"];
    [self.myRecordsCombo addItemsWithObjectValues:self.myRecords];


 }

 // C Method
 int
 getData()
 {
     char name[128];
     NSString *str;

    while(/*traverse through data for combo box */){
        NSString *tempName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", name];         
        str = [str stringByAppendingString:tempName];

        ....
    }
    NSLog(str); //will be passed to awakeFromNib and populate to combo box


 }
```

Can't seem to get the right strings as it will end up with garbage variables.

Comment: Do you want to add items in NSComboBox programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create the list of items. (NSArray).

```
NSArray *items = @[@"Apple", @"Ball", @"Cat", @"Doll"];
```

Remove all existing items as by default three items gets added to combo box.

```
[self.comboBox removeAllItems];
```

Now add your items to the combo box:

```
[self.comboBox addItemsWithObjectValues:items];
```

Comment: What if I will add more items aside from Apple, Ball, Cat and Doll based on the result in the while-loop?

Comment: i'm looking for something that works like array_push() in php (http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_push.asp)

Comment: @newbieMACuser see `NSMutableArray`'s methods which begin with "add" and "insert"

Comment: @newbieMACuser: As justin said, you have different methods that you may use, if you are changing the array, then use MutableArray and that will update the combobox...

Comment: first of all, why you want to loop through each for the array element and add them individually? Since you can add all of them in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
-(void)someMethod{
    [self.comboBox removeAllItems];
    yourArr=@[@"Item1,Item2,Item3,Item4"];//Assuming some values
    NSUInteger i=0;
    while (i!=yourArr.count)
    {
       //Below you are sending data to the another method which will populate the combo box
        NSLog(@"%@",yourArr[i]);
        [self yourMethod:yourArr[i]];
        i++;
    }
  }

 //Below is your different method
-(void)yourMethod:(NSString*)yourStr
{
 [self.comboBox addItemWithObjectValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",yourStr]];
}


//After seeing your question below is the Conversion from C to Objective-C

-(void)someMethod
{
    NSArray *arr1=[self.comboBox.objectValues[0] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
       NSUInteger i=0;
    NSString *str;


    while(i<arr1.count-1){
        i++;
            NSLog(@"%@",arr1[i]);
        NSString *tempName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", arr1[i]];
        str = [str stringByAppendingString:tempName];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",str); //will be passed
}
```

Comment: I would want to store the data first in a string variable then pass it since populating of combo box is in another method. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What's the alternative for self? I get "undeclared identifier self" .

Comment: I have to use C method though. will try to check how to integrate C and objective-c.

Comment: I have updated the ans. Please refer and let me know if you need some more help